# printing array in reverse order avoiding duplicates c++

Tags: c++

So, I have to print out my array in reverse order, avoiding duplicates.
Code works fine, except one mistake:
The output has to be:

```
100000
9995
992
22
14
```

It prints to the screen

```
-292742
100000
9995
992
22
14
```

Where did this first garbage value came from, I have no idea. I think mistake is in this particular function, but I don't know where. I need to avoid this garbage value. The rest of the implementation works perfectly.

```
int last;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = lengthOfArray-1; i >=0; i--){
        if(last == arr[i]){
            ++count;
        }else{
        cout << last << endl;
        count = 1;
        }
        last = arr[i];
    }
     if (count > 0) {
        cout << last << endl;
    }
```

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize `last`, otherwise it will be filled with garbage and according to your logic, it will print `last`.

```
int last = arr[lengthOfArray-1];
int count = 0;
for(int i = lengthOfArray-1; i >=0; i--){
    if(last == arr[i]){
        ++count;
    } else{
        cout << last << endl;
        count = 1;
    }
    last = arr[i];
}
if (count > 0) {
    cout << last << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an uninitialized value (`last`) and first compare it to `arr[i]` and then output it if it is not equal to `a[i]`. Using an uninitialized value will be undefined behavior. In this case last happens to be initialized to `-292742` which explains the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
else{
    last = arr[i];
    cout << last << endl;
    count = 1;
}
```

your else statement should be like this